# carry along with another element and print it out

Tags: java

the tile doesn't clarify my question,
So this is part of my program:

```java
public static void selectionsort(int[] userID, double[] donation, PrintWriter output) {
    int min, swap;
    for (int i = 0; i < userID.length - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (int m = i + 1; m < userID.length; m++) {
            if (userID[m] < userID[i]) {
                min = m;
                swap = userID[min];
                userID[min] = userID[i];
                userID[i] = swap;
            }
        }
        output.println(userID[i] + "   " + donation[i]);
    }
}
```

my array is following:

```
456             250.0
123            175.34
345            123.06
```

but when my method goes to

```
output.println(userID[i]+"   "+donation[i]);
```

it print out like this:

```
123   250.0
345   175.34
456   123.06
```

i want to maintain the match-up of ID numbers and donations. For example, 456 should always be associated with 250.00, no matter where 456 moves. how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because within that method, only the `userID` array is being sorted, while the `donation` array is not being shuffled accordingly. And there is no other mapping between the `userID` array elements and `donation` array elements, hence the print of both array elements wouldn't be  showing the previous association.

Hence in your method, whenever you swap places of `userID` array elements, you must also swap places of the corresponding `donation` array elements. That can be done as below:

```
public static void selectionsort(int[] userID, double[] donation, PrintWriter output) {
    int min, swap;
    for (int i = 0; i < userID.length - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (int m = i + 1; m < userID.length; m++) {
            if (userID[m] < userID[i]) {
                min = m;
                swap = userID[min];
                userID[min] = userID[i];
                userID[i] = swap;

                swap=donation[min];
                donation[min]=donation[i];
                donation[i]=swap;
            }
        }
        output.println(userID[i] + "   " + donation[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: but donation[] is double in my method and swap is int, isnt that going to be an error there?

Comment: nvm, i could just add another double parameter there

Comment: Yes, you would just need another double field to swap the element. The bottomline is that you need to swap the donation array elements whenever you are swapping userId array elements. Or else you would need to use some other data structure, but I guess that's not something you would want.